# SharePoint Web Services Site Gone in IIS 8.0 (SP2013)

Tags: iis

In my SharePoint environment the site "SharePoint Web Service" site is missing from IIS Sites list, is there a way to recreate it?

I have seen a guide on [here](http://www.avanadeblog.com/sharepointasg/2010/11/fix-iis-web-site-sharepoint-web-services-is-missing-event-id-8306-event-id-8011.html) but it seems to be for SharePoint 2010. Is there a guide for SharePoint 2013? Or what code would I need to change from the 2010 guide?

Answer (score 0):

I think the same is applicable to Sharepoint 2013. According to this [article](http://masieden.blogspot.in/2013/01/missing-sharepoint-web-services-site-in.html)

You can test it in your machine. and you mighthave to change assembly version of Sharepoint dlls.

Comment: hello thank you for the reply, its similar to the guide i have tired when i run the code on my server powershell returns "you cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" relating to this line.

$Method = $webservice.GetMethod("ProvisionLocal", "Instance, NonPublic", $null, @(), $null)

Comment: Are you getting anything in $webservice? you can try with $webservice = [System.Type]::GetType("Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisWebServiceSettings, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c") . confirm the PublicKeyToken from GAC

Comment: how do i check if i am getting anything in $webservice? i tried with altering from 14.0.0.0 to 15.0.0.0 and have got my PublicKeyToken From the C:\windows\assembly\GAC folder but still returns the error You Cannot Call a method on a null-valued expression

Comment: Add-PSSnapin "microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell"

$webservice = [system.Type]::GetType("Microsoft.Sharepoint.Administration.SPIisWebServiceSettings, Microsoft.Sharepoint, Verstion=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")

$instance = $webservice::Default

$method = $webservice.GetMethod("ProvisionLocal", "instance, NonPublic", $null, @(), $null)

$method.invoke($instance, $null)

$method = $webservice.GetMethod("Provision", "instance, Public", $null, @(), $null)

$method.invoke($instance, $null)

Comment: Are you running this under admin privileges?

Comment: use this : $webservice = [System.Type]::GetType("Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPIisWebServiceSettings, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c")

$Instance = $webservice::Default

$Method = $webservice.GetMethod("ProvisionLocal", "Instance, NonPublic", $null, @(), $null)

Comment: This is working on SP 2013 machine

Comment: hello i ran the code in the as administrator in SharePoint 2013 Management shell and it still returns you cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Comment: Have you tries with latest code that i mentioned. Its working fine at my end.

Comment: yea i tried it, there must be something abnormal on my system, but who knows what

Comment: Can you post your latest code?

Comment: i just copied to the code you used exactly as it is

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: This should work. Because it was giving me same error. But second time it worked properly. Just check if all your parameters are correct.

Comment: the publickeytoken=71e9bce111e9429c should that be related to the publickeytoken for my sharepoint site?

Comment: In your case also, it should be same. Please check if this is same.

Comment: yes its identical code copied and pasted from here.